# how to trigger a PHP webpage after lsync copies a file

Tags: rsync, php, lua

I have the following logic in my /etc/lsyncd/lsyncd.lua file

```
require "lsync-widgets"
sync {
     widget_sync,
     source="/tmp/folder1",
     target="/tmp/folder2/"

}
```

And then in my lsync-widgets.lua file I have the following logic:

```
settings {
     logfacility=daemon,
 }
widget_sync = {
     maxProcesses = 5,
     onCreate = "rsync -W --backup ^sourcePathname ^target",
     onModify = "rsync -W --backup ^sourcePathname ^target",
}
```

THis works in that anytime I drop a file or change a file in /tmp/folder1, it copies that file over to /tmp/folder2. 
But now I need to trigger a php webpage running on a local server once the file is in /tmp/folder2.
Not too sure how to accomplish this.

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you simply add another command to your existing create/modify shell command, in the style of `onCreate = "rsync -W --backup ^sourcePathname ^target; php mycommand.php ..."`

Comment: `[OT]`. @dot about https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/391794/results-from-posixtz-command-looks-odd-for-one-time-zone you don't have to delete a question when it's a duplicate. Leaving it in can help other users find the right information (especially considering thay here, it's not an _exact_ duplicate even if the same answers apply).